# Expected value $E[X_i] = X_i$ is that reasonable?

Tags: expected-value

In a regression course, there is an exercise in which it is given that

$y_{i} = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1} \cdot x_{i}$

- What is the expected value of $y_{i}$ expressed in terms of the parameters and $x_{i}$ ?

In the solution of this exercise it is written that,

$E[y_{i}] = E[\beta_{0} + \beta_{1} \cdot x_{i}] = \beta_{0} + E[\beta_{1} \cdot x_{i}] = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1} \cdot E[x_{i}] = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1} \cdot x_{i}$

How can it be that $E[x_{i}] = x_{i} $ ?

Is there something wrong with the solution or do I miss something?

Thanks

Comment: Add the self-study tag please.

Comment: Can you please share the source? I suspect it is an abuse of notation.

Comment: If $x_i$ is not random, then $E]x_i] = x_i$.  I agree with @gunes, though, this should have been clarified in the exercise.